If I sacrifice a Forsaken Miner to the card Eaten Alive do I get the miner back?
If I sacrifice a Forsaken Miner to a Eaten Alive do I get to pay a black to get the miner back? I'm targeting my opponents creature with Eaten Alive.

I refer you to your own comment.

Yes, that combo works.
You commit a crime when you successfully target something. For a spell, that happens when the spell has been successfully cast, i.e. after all its costs have been paid. Sacrificing the Miner is a cost of Eaten Alive, so the Miner will be in the graveyard when the crime event happens and its ability will trigger, allowing you to return it to the battlefield.

601.2h The player pays the total cost. [..]
601.2i Once the steps described in 601.2a–h are completed, effects that modify the characteristics of the spell as it’s cast are applied, then the spell becomes cast.


700.13. Some cards refer to committing a crime. A player commits a crime as that player casts a spell, activates an ability, or puts a triggered ability on the stack and that spell or ability targets at least one opponent;


This is confirmed by Forsaken Miner's first Gatherer ruling.
